# Userdefaults Tableview placemark Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, tableview, nsuserdefaults

I am using **uitableview**. I am trying to save the placemark when i have selected a cell. From the code below i have added a tableview and when i select a cell the placemark will be shown. But i'm having trouble saving it because when i go to another view controller and go back it doesn't show. I have researched and find that i need to use **UserDefaults** but i have no clue how to use it. can someone point me how can i achieve this. Thanks

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    let contactsCell = app.helper.contacts[indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel?.text = contactsCell

    return cell!
}


func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    let contactToCall = app.helper.contacts[indexPath.row]
    app.helper.contactSelected = contactToCall

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        if cell.isSelected {
            cell.accessoryType = .checkmark


        }
    }

}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need UserDefaults unless you want to maintain state after the app has been closed and restarted, and once you start storing user defaults, you're likely to want to store more - so it makes sense to create a defaults data class to store the selected index and any other 'stuff' you may need.

In this example, I'm going to load the defaults on `viewDidLoad` and store the defaults on each select / deselect.  If you have other values stored, you should have additional storage calls.

Create a class for storing your data

```
class MyDefaultsData : NSObject, NSCoding
{
    var selectedIndexPath : IndexPath?
    var otherStuff : String?

    override init()
    {
        // you can set up default values here if you need them
        selectedIndexPath = nil
        otherStuff = nil
    }

    // archiving code
    func encode(with aCoder: NSCoder)
    {
        // you can't store IndexPath directly, so split it into row and section
        if selectedIndexPath == nil
        {
            // set invalid values which we can identify later
            aCoder.encode(-1, forKey: "indexSection")
            aCoder.encode(-1, forKey: "indexRow")
        }
        else
        {
            aCoder.encode(selectedIndexPath!.section, forKey: "indexSection")
            aCoder.encode(selectedIndexPath!.row, forKey: "indexRow")
        }
        aCoder.encode(otherStuff, forKey: "otherStuff")
    }

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        let indexSection = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "indexSection")
        let indexRow = aDecoder.decodeInteger(forKey: "indexRow")
        if indexSection != -1 && indexRow != -1  // if no row is selected, these values will both be -1
        {
            selectedIndexPath   = IndexPath(row: indexRow, section: indexSection)
        }
        else
        {
            selectedIndexPath = nil
        }

        self.otherStuff     = aDecoder.decodeObject(forKey: "otherStuff") as? String
    }

}
```

Define a variable of your default data within the ViewController

```
var defaultData         = MyDefaultsData()
```

Load the data in your `viewDidLoad`

```
override func viewDidLoad()
{
    loadDefaults()
}

func loadDefaults()
{
    var dataDefaults : MyDefaultsData?
    if let data = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "NSDefaultsTest") as? Data
    {
        dataDefaults =  NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(with: data) as? MyDefaultsData

        self.defaultData.otherStuff = dataDefaults?.otherStuff ?? "No value found"

        self.defaultData.selectedIndexPath = dataDefaults?.selectedIndexPath
    }
}
```

then you use that default data within `cellForRowAt`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell")

    let contactsCell = app.helper.contacts[indexPath.row]
    cell!.textLabel?.text = contactsCell

    // set or clear the checkmark
    if selectedIndexPath == indexPath
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .checkmark
    }
    else
    {
        cell.accessoryType = .none
    }
    return cell!
}
```

When you change the selected row, you need to reload both the previous selected row (if any) and the currently selected row, to get the checkmark drawn

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    let previousIndexPath = defaultData.selectedIndexPath
    if previousIndexPath != indexPath
    {
        defaultData.selectedIndexPath = indexPath
    }
    else
    {
        defaultData.selectedIndexPath = nil
    }
    storeDefaults()


    if previousIndexPath != nil
    {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [previousIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
    }
    if defaultData.selectedIndexPath != nil
    {
        tableView.reloadRows(at: [defaultData.selectedIndexPath!], with: .automatic)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your respond. Yes i am trying to mantain the checkmark even if the app closes.

Comment: Thank you so much!